# determine if array is heap data structure

Tags: java

I ve got an issue with the ArrayIndexOutofBound error when trying to determine whether data is heap following the 2i + 1/2 formula child-parent relationship. Do you know how can I resolve the issue?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
      if ((array[i] < array[2*i + 1]) || (array[i] < array[2*i + 2]))
    {
       bool = false;
          ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted code seems to be missing some important bits - what is `arr`?

Comment: sry. it should be array. I have just posted a snipped of the main code and requirement for heap. But in checking whether the data is a heap you get ArrayIndexOutofBound.

Comment: Yes, make sure you don't evaluate `array[n]` for `n >= length`.

Comment: What do you mean "data is heap"? There are many ways of constructing a heap, some of which use arrays as part of their data structure.

Comment: i don't have to construct the heap. I ll have to say whether some array's data is constructed as heap

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking for the boundaries of the array first, and if it contains enough elements, then you can compare them:

```
if ((array.length >= 2*i + 2) 
   && ((array[i] < array[2*i + 1]) || (array[i] < array[2*i + 2])))
{
   bool = false;
      ....
}
```

Comment: your first condition array.length >= 2*i + 2 is true if the node has two children but the node may have just one 2*i + 1. It doesnt work.

Comment: it's just an example, exact behaviour depends on what you need to do, if the node has or doesn't have the children

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop guard allows `i == array.length -1`.  But inside the loop, you look for element `2 * i + 2`.  That's `2 * array.length`.  That's way beyond the end of the array, and will always throw an excpetion (except when i == 0).

Change your for-loop guard to `i < ((array.length / 2) - 1)`, so that the maximal value of `2 * i + 2` is array.length - 1.  Also, ensure you test this both for arrays of even and odd length; I think the logic will work in only one case.